# ReactJS state updates one step behind

Tags: reactjs, axios, jsx

I am trying to create a simple table using ReactJS to display user information. Here's how the general code structure looks like:

```
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  state = { 
    data : [] 
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // initializes state with data from db
    axios.get("link/").then(res => {
      this.setState({data: res.data});
    });

    // I should be able to call this.getData() instead
    // of rewriting the axios.get() function but if I do so,
    // my data will not show up

  }
  
  // retrieves array of data from db
  getData = () => {
    axios.get("link/").then(res => {
      this.setState({data: res.data});
    });
  }  

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ChildComponent data={this.state.data} refetch={this.getData} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Each of the generated rows should have a delete function, where I'll delete the entry from the database based on a given id. After the deletion, I want to retrieve the latest data from the parent component to be redisplayed again.

```
class ChildComponent extends React.Component {

  // deletes the specified entry from database
  deleteData = (id) => {
    axios.get("deleteLink/" + id).then(res => {
      console.log(res);
      // calls function from parent component to 
      // re-fetch the latest data from db
      this.props.refetch();

    }).catch(err => {console.log(err)});
  }

  render() {
    let rows = null;
    if(this.props.data.length) {
      // map the array into individual rows
      rows = this.props.data.map(x => {
        return (
          <tr>
            <td>{x.id}</td>
            <td>{x.name}</td>
            <td>
               <button onClick={() => {
                 this.deleteData(x.id)
                }}>
                  Delete
               </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        )
      })

    }

    return (
      <div>
        <table>
          <thead></thead>
          <tbody>
            {rows}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

The two problems which I encountered here are:

1. Logically, I should be able to call this.getData() from within componentDidMount(), but if I do so, the table doesn't load.
2. Whenever I try to delete a row, the table will not reflect the update even though the entry is removed from the database. The table will only be updated when I refresh the page or delete another row. Problem is, the component is always lagging behind by 1 update.

So far I have tried:

1. `this.forceUpdate()` - doesn't work
2. `this.setState({})` - empty setState doesn't work either
3. changing `componentDidMount()` to `componentDidUpdate()` - error showing that I have "reached maximum depth" or something along that line
4. adding async await in front of axios - doesn't work

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

---

**EDIT**: I did some debugging and tracked down the issue, which is not relevant to my question. My `deleteData()` which is located in ChildComponent uses `axios.post()` instead of `axios.get()`, which I overlooked.

```
deleteData = (id) => {
    axios.post("deleteLink/", id).then(res => {
      console.log(res);
      // calls function from parent component to 
      // re-fetch the latest data from db
      this.props.refetch();

    }).catch(err => {console.log(err)});
  }
```

In order for `axios.post()` to return a response, in order to perform `.then()`, you'll need to add a `res.json()` to the routing codes.

Comment: can you log res after making the api call? also it looks weird when you are updating the state, is it a typo? it should be `this.setState({data: res.data})`

Comment: Yeah, that's a typo on my part. The response contains the usual headers, array of data, and a status 200 - nothing unusual about that. The deleteData() function did run when I click the delete button. However, it did not trigger a component re-render until I delete another row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should map data into your child.

Change your parent like this:

```
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  state = { 
      data : [] 
  }

  componentDidMount() {
      this.getData();
  }
    
  getData = () => axios.get("link/").then(res => this.setState({data: res.data});
    
  deleteData = (id) => axios.get("deleteLink/" + id).then(res => this.getData())
       .catch(err => { console.log(err) });

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <table>
          <thead></thead>
          <tbody>
            {this.state.data.map(x => <ChildComponent row={x} deleteData={this.deleteData} />)}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

And your child component should be like this

```
const ChildComponent = ({row,deleteData}) => (
      <tr>
        <td>{row.id}</td>
        <td>{row.name}</td>
        <td><button onClick={() => deleteData(row.id)}>Delete</button></td>
      </tr >
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have another question, if you don't mind. I would like to move the table into a child component because I might add some other components later on. Is there a solution which would allow row generation in my child component instead? I might want to have multiple child components that all share the same data from the parent component. My concern is they will not rerender even though the parent's state is updated.

Comment: No problem, react update with state changes(it's a law), if your component didn't render with `state` changes you should double-check your structure, maybe your state doesn't affect the component.

Comment: If you need help making your app, make a sandbox from your code ill help you.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I did some debugging and found that it is an entirely different issue causing the delay. It has to do with my backend and axios not returning a response consistently. I managed to fixed the problem but thanks for your help!

Comment: Happy to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

I can't find an issue in your code, the only way I can help is to tell you how I would debug it.

edit parent like so:

```
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  state = { 
    data : [] 
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // You are right when you say this should works, so 
    // stick to it until the bug is fixed
    
    console.log("parent mounted");
    this.getData();
  }
  
  // retrieves array of data from db
  getData = () => {
    console.log("fetching data");

    axios.get("link/").then(res => {
      console.log("fetched data", res.data);
      this.setState({data: res.data});
    });
  }  

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ChildComponent 
          data={this.state.data}
          refetch={this.getData}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

and in the child component add these 2 lifecycle methods just for debugging purposes:

```
componentDidMount () {
   console.log("child mounted", this.props.data)     
}

componentDidUpdate (prevProps) {
   console.log("old data", prevProps.data);
   console.log("new data", this.props.data);
   console.log("data are equal", prevProps.data === this.props.data);
}
```

if you can share the logs I can try help you more

Comment: I tracked down the problem which is unrelated to the code snippet itself. Turns out my backend wasn't responding consistently. The componentDidUpdate() part looks pretty useful, though. I'll try that the next time I encounter an error, thanks.